# C++ 'Ptr' in 'class B' does not name a type error in typedef'ed shared_ptr

Tags: c++11

I want to use typedef'ed shared_ptr object in both class A and class B.

I am getting compilation error - 'Ptr' in 'class B' does not name a type error'
although i am forward declaring the class.

Here is my setup :

**A.h**

```
#pragma once
#include<memory>

class B;//Forward Declaration

class A
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
    B::Ptr get_b_ptr();
};
```

**B.h**

```
#pragma once
#include<memory>

class A;//Forward Declaration

class B
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<B> Ptr;
    A::Ptr get_a_ptr();
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include<A.h>
#include<B.h>

B::Ptr A::get_b_ptr()
{
    B::Ptr bptr;
    return bptr;
}
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include<B.h>
#include<A.h>

A::Ptr B::get_a_ptr()
{
    A::Ptr aptr;
    return aptr;
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include<A.h>
#include<B.h>
int main()
{
    A::Ptr ptr1;
    B::Ptr ptr2;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following compilation error:

A.h:10:5:'Ptr' in 'class B' does not name a type

Comment: When `B` is only forward declared, using `B::Ptr` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible with classes but it **is** possible with namespaces. Here is how I suggest going about this problem:

A.h

```
#pragma once
#include<memory>

namespace b
{
class B;//Forward Declaration
typedef std::shared_ptr<B> Ptr;
}

namespace a
{
class A
{
public:
    b::Ptr get_b_ptr();
};
}
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
#include<memory>

namespace a
{
class A;//Forward Declaration
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
}

namespace b
{
class B
{
public:
    a::Ptr get_a_ptr();
};
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include<A.h>
#include<B.h>

b::Ptr a::A::get_b_ptr()
{
    b::Ptr bptr;
    return bptr;
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include<B.h>
#include<A.h>

a::Ptr b::B::get_a_ptr()
{
    a::Ptr aptr;
    return aptr;
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to keep same namespace name for both A and B.

Comment: @aditya1811 Well, you can remove all the namespaces, but keep the `typedef`s outside of the classes. Then, of course you have to name them properly like `typedef std::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;` for example.

Comment: That means there will be a conflict between A::Ptr and B::Ptr if i tyepdef them in the same namespace (but under different class)

Comment: @aditya1811 The way you want to do is not possible to have `typedef`s inside classes. So, they have to be outside classes, and if they are in the same scope, then they need to have different names.

Comment: So to summarize, if i want to use same namespace for A and B, and want to use Ptr for both typedefs then i just can't use it.
I need to define the typedefs outside the classes like APtr and BPtr.
Is that right?